# Alguna solución para el problema max_connections_per_hour

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

[image: Mi página esta conectada y en momentos se cae]

ya revise el código y encuentro todo bien,determine usar phpmyadmin para revisar los procesos y detenerlos pero no me permite. Alguien me puede dar algún consejo o sugerencia. La pagina se activa en unos minutos o quizás horas y sin embargo termina siendo inestable

Comment: Saludos, debes agregar el código que tienes, y por favor no agregues capturas de pantalla, mejor copia y pega el código y el error en formato de texto. ;)

Comment: Hola. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega la forma en que te estás conectando a la base de datos desde `mysqli`. Puede que el problema esté ocurriendo debido a que usas conexiones persistentes. Pero también pueden haber otros scripts de PHP, o en la consola u otros que se están conectando a la base de datos.

Comment: algo pasa que estas dejando las conexiones sin cerrar. al conectarte a la base haces una conexion, extraestodo y cierras, ese es el funcionamiento correcto, revisa tu codigo; https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php